# How to clear dynamic array in C++ and how much is on the stack?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, securezeromemory

I have a struct in my C++ program. At the end of my function I do a delete [] to free the allocated memory. How do I erase all elements in code without doing a for() loop?

```
struct sServerStatus
{
    TCHAR sServer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1]; // The NetBIOS name of the computer + 1 null terminating character.
};
sServerStatus *sServersType1 = new sServerStatus[1024];
```

Q1. How do I clear the array after I fill some of the items up? Do I use SecureZeroMemory?

```
SecureZeroMemory(sServersType1 , sizeof(sServersType1 ));
```

Q2. What is on the stack? I assume the allocated space on the stack is just MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1 and the 1024 elements are on the heap?

Comment: I've not used SecureZeroMemory but you'd probably want to do something like `SecureZeroMemory( sServersType1, sizeof(sServerStatus) * 1024)`.

Answer (score 3):

1. `new sServerStatus[1024];` will allocate 1024 `sServerStatus` instances *on the heap*.
2. Each one of those has `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1` `TCHAR`s. (Also on the heap since that's where the objects are allocated.)

**The only thing on the stack is the pointer** `sServersType1`**.**

To clean everything up, note that you didn't use `new` to allocate (2) so you don't need to use `delete` either. That memory will be freed once an `sServerStatus` instance is destructed.

But you will need to free the memory you allocated using `new`. Do do this you need to write `delete[] sServersType1`. Note carefully the `[]`.

Comment: I mean, how do I clear all elements in code without doing a for() loop _before_ I get to the end of the function and run a delete[]? As in the function has maybe 5000 lines of code and I need to frequently clear out the array as the function is running.

Comment: I think he's talking 'clean' up as in secure erase. You didn't address Q1